# Side by side geom_bar plots of 2 different columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

so I got 2 plots, that work perfectly fine on their own.
I'm trying to show them side by side, bars next to each other as pretty as possible, but it's just not working out. Trying to compare past and current food expenditure of some 600 people.

```
  ggplot(data=survey,aes(x=Past.FoodExp))+
  geom_bar()+
  geom_text(stat ='count',aes(label =..count.., vjust = -0.2))
```

```
  ggplot(data=survey,aes(x=Current.FoodExp))+
  geom_bar()+
  geom_text(stat ='count',aes(label =..count.., vjust = -0.2))
```

This is what I [tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSN4J.png), but it didn't give me a result I wanted.

[image]

```
ggplot(data=survey, aes(y=Past.foodExp, x=Current.FoodExp)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

As you can see, it shows my ranges on both x and y axes, and I need it on only x, while y being the total count of people I surveyed. Any of you got an idea how to go around this and present it properly? Thanks.

---

**Reproducible example**

dput(head(survey,10))

```r
structure(list(Past.FoodExp = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0-100\x80", "101-200\x80", "201-300\x80", 
"300\x80+"), class = "factor"), Current.FoodExp = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0-100\x80", 
"101-200\x80", "201-300\x80", "300\x80+"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @dc37 Yeah, gimme a sec

Comment: I uploaded the csv here
https://easyupload.io/va2r62

survey<-read.csv(
  file="repex.csv",
  header=TRUE,
  sep=",",
  quote = "\"")

Comment: just copy paste the output of `dput(survey)`. If it is too long, you can do `dput(head(survey,10))`

Comment: here you go
dput(head(survey,10))
structure(list(Past.FoodExp = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0-100\200", "101-200\200", "201-300\200", 
"300\200+"), class = "factor"), Current.FoodExp = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0-100\200", 
"101-200\200", "201-300\200", "300\200+"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reshape your dataframe into a longer format. You can use `pivot_longer` function for example:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

survey %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "val")

# A tibble: 20 x 2
   var             val          
   <chr>           <fct>        
 1 Past.FoodExp    "101-200\x80"
 2 Current.FoodExp "101-200\x80"
 3 Past.FoodExp    "0-100\x80"  
 4 Current.FoodExp "101-200\x80"
 5 Past.FoodExp    "201-300\x80"
 6 Current.FoodExp "300\x80+"   
 7 Past.FoodExp    "300\x80+"   
 8 Current.FoodExp "300\x80+"   
 9 Past.FoodExp    "201-300\x80"
10 Current.FoodExp "201-300\x80"
11 Past.FoodExp    "300\x80+"   
12 Current.FoodExp "201-300\x80"
13 Past.FoodExp    "201-300\x80"
14 Current.FoodExp "300\x80+"   
15 Past.FoodExp    "300\x80+"   
16 Current.FoodExp "300\x80+"   
17 Past.FoodExp    "201-300\x80"
18 Current.FoodExp "300\x80+"   
19 Past.FoodExp    "201-300\x80"
20 Current.FoodExp "300\x80+"
```

So, with this structure, you can now pass it easily in `ggplot2` as follow:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

survey %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, fill = var))+
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge())+
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = ..count..), vjust = -0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted!